# How and what should i set C# Xamarin IOS Auth0 callback (URL mismatch)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, auth0, callbackurl

Looking at Auth0 settings, I see that I need to set callback URL for my users to be redirected to a different page in the app once logged in. SOF seems to be using localhost URLs, the documentation uses a specific format
[https://auth0.github.io/auth0-oidc-client-net/documentation/getting-started/callbacks.html#:~:text=Callback%20URLs%20are%20the%20URLs,an%20id_token%20%2C%20access_token%20and%20refresh_token%20](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-oidc-client-net/documentation/getting-started/callbacks.html#:%7E:text=Callback%20URLs%20are%20the%20URLs,an%20id_token%20%2C%20access_token%20and%20refresh_token%20).
in either cases I keep getting "The provided redirect_uri is not in the list of allowed callback URLs"
My setting on Auth0:
com.mycompany.myapp://MyTenant.us.auth0.com/ios/com.mycompany.myapp/callback

the app bundle identifier is correctly set to com.mycompany.myapp

following https://auth0.com/blog/developing-mobile-apps-with-xamarin-forms-and-azure-functions/
my info.plist also is populated with needed URL package identifier.

Comment: did you save the url in auth0 configuration page?

Comment: Yes, I raised a support ticket and awaiting response

Comment: you can update the question after you get a solution.

Comment: Will do when I get one

Comment: This worked BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER://TENANT_NAME.us.auth0.com/ios/BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER/callback

Comment: but the code crashes on LoginAsync on actual iphone but works fine on Simulator. I later ran into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489558/paid-membership-adding-apple-account-to-visual-studio-xamarin-2022-unable-to-l so I am now learning Swift as that page loaded fine on IPhone when signing code on Xcode :/ .......

Comment: im running into this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71489558/paid-membership-adding-apple-account-to-visual-studio-xamarin-2022-unable-to-l