# (paid membership) adding apple account to Visual Studio Xamarin 2022 unable to load provisioning profiles

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

tried :

- removing provisioning profiles from AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS
- removing and adding apple account from VS
- removing trusted devices from apple account
  running VS 17.1.1

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your account in the link below.

   https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1

   For more details for this, you could refer to the MS docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?context=xamarin%2Fios&tabs=windows#view-signing-certificates-and-provisioning-profiles
2. In the Visual Studio, check the role of your account is Agent or not.

   Visual Studio> Tools> Options> Xamarin> Apple Account

   [image]

Comment: my account shows agent, the issue presists on MacOS VS and WIndows VS. i opened an issue with apple and awaiting response. I can sign and deploy fine on native swift Xcode

Comment: I rechecked the issue. The same one has been reported and would be fixed in the future. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cannot-load-Apple-certificates/1692185